# Border independent margin with css?

Tags: html, css

I have a case where the border-width is changing when hovering. I'm using box-sizing: border-box. So to keep the content fixed padding+border-width must be constant.

I wounder if there is a way in CSS to define the distance from outside of a divs border to its content?

See the example below. I would like to only set the border-width in .foo:hover and not the padding.

```css
.button {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.foo {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.foo:hover {
  border-width: 5px;
}

/* find a way to remove this */
.button.foo:hover {
  padding: 6px; 
}
```

```html
<div class='button foo'>
hello
</div>
```

Background for the question:
I would like to define multiple styles (foo) which includes the border-width. A component (button) should describe the sizing such as the margin. But a component may change styles (with different border-width). So I prefer that the component sizing is independent of the style.

Comment: use outline or box-shadow instead of border

Comment: Good suggestion. But the real case is more complicated and it is not possible to use outline or box-shadow.

Comment: then share you *real* case